# How do I mock Object.getClass?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm working on a Java project want to write a unit test for an .equals method I have in a DTO. In the .equals method, there is a .getClass() method called by both objects under test. I want to mock this, but I can't tell what type of object it wants. I tried,

`when(mockRoomInv.getClass()).thenReturn(RoomInv.class);`

but sure as heck didn't do anything. What is the return type of getClass, and how do I manipulate it?

Comment: Unless I am missing something - there is no point in mocking a method that already exists and that you are not going to change, and ANY method inherited from Object exists in every class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object.getClass()` is a `final` method, so you cannot mock it with Mockito.

You can mock `static` and `final` methods (as this one) and even `private` methods with Powermock (it's a quite cool tool ;) available at https://github.com/powermock/powermock.

You can use it with Mockito as explained [in the Mockito wiki article](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito). There you will find some useful examples.

Answer (score 9):

As `Object.getClass()` is final, you cannot mock that method with Mockito. I would strongly advice you to refactor your code to inject the class in another way. If that's not possible, you could try out [powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/), where you could mock any final method. `Object.getClass()` is a bit special, so be sure to set `MockGateway.MOCK_GET_CLASS_METHOD = true` in powermock.